# Htaccess 301 redirect dynamic URL

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I don't know a whole lot about *.htaccess* rules so forgive and help me ask the correct question.

Currently I have a *.htaccess* rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^surveys/(\S+)/directory/(\d+)/(\d+)/entry/(\d+)/?$ directories/index.cfm?sFuseAction=XXX.YYYY.ZZZZ&nDirectoryID=$2&nEntryID=$4&nCategoryID=$3&sDirectory=$1 [NC,L]
```

which I want to do a 301 redirect to:

```
RewriteRule ^(\S+)/directory/(\d+)/(\d+)/entry/(\d+)/?$     directories/index.cfm?sFuseAction=XXX.YYYY.ZZZZ&nDirectoryID=$2&nEntryID=$4&nCategoryID=$3&sDirectory=$1 [NC,L]
```

I'm unsure of the correct syntax to go about making these redirect correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a 301 redirect you will have to use the full URI path including the FQDN and protocol. Like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(\S+)/directory/(\d+)/(\d+)/entry/(\d+)/?$     http://www.example.com/directories/index.cfm?sFuseAction=XXX.YYYY.ZZZZ&nDirectoryID=$2&nEntryID=$4&nCategoryID=$3&sDirectory=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I notice you don't include anything to indicate this is a 301, i've seen other examples of using [R=301,NC,L] at the end... is there a reason for this?